# Laravel populate form with input groups

Tags: php, forms, laravel, input

I am looking for the way to bind data in to form with input groups. 
For exmaple I have these inputs:

```
Form::text('purchaser[address]');
Form::text('seller[address]');
```

and I want to bind data from my variable - $purchaser which has a field 'address' and $seller also with field 'address'. I know that forms can be filled using laravel

```
Form::model
```

but I can't find example how to use it for input groups. Is there even such a possibility or I have to do it manually?

Comment: Do you also have your purchaser defined in a model, or just in the database? e.g. `Purchaser.php` in your `app/models`?

Comment: Yes I have the model and the $purchaser is an object of this model

Comment: @PiotrSuchanek Check my answer, you can do what you need

Comment: Could you please post your model? If `purchaser` is a publicly accessible property of your model, the code you posted should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I got it wrong I suppose. You want just fill the `address` field value, not `address` relation, but with a group of models, right?

So, you can easily do this:

```
$purchaser = Purchaser::with('address')->find($someId);

$groups = new Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$groups->put('purchaser', $purchaser);
$groups->put('another_model', $anotherModel);

// then
Form::model($groups->toArray())
  Form::text('purchaser[address]')
  Form::text('another_model[some_field]')
```

---

First you need to `load` the `address`, then you need to call it in array manner:

```
// eager load
$purchaser = Purchaser::with('address')->find($someId);
// or lazy load
$purchaser->load('address');

// then:
Form::model($purchaser, ...)
  Form::text('address[street]')
  Form::text('address[city]')
  // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, I think you're pretty close:

```
Form::model($purchaser);
```

Then, if you want an `<input type="text">`  with the address value in it, you would call:

```
Form::text("address");
```

And Laravel should supply the value from the model for you.

Please note, this assumes that you have a model for `$purchaser` defined. If not, do that first.

Usually, I just do `<input>` elements manually as I feel I have more control. In this case:

```
<input type="text" name="address" value="{{ $purchaser->address }}" class="..."/>
```

And I can edit and modify that whenever I want, especially the `class` and `value` attributes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That'll do it. The $purchaser->address should work as long as the address is defined in the Purchaser model.

Comment: I know you can do it this way, but my form is a very large and 'address' field is also present in other places, so I used input groups. I'd like to now fill them in some automated way.

Comment: Do you want to show an example of what you're using right now? I'm a little confused what you mean. Post the html mark up of your of your *input groups*